# Sql query (with Desc order and Limit) not working on python (OpenERP)

Tags: python, postgresql, openerp-7

I've been struggling with this issue all day and tried all possible ways that i know.here's the problem:

The field that i'm working on has a format like this:

XXX-year example: 001-2014 (String)

suppose that we have these records:

- 001-2014
- 011-2014
- 013-2013

the result that i expect to get is 011-2014 (in other words the earliest year with the biggest value)

I'v wrote this query that works fine on PostgreSql:

```
select split_part(numero_bl, '-', 1) as part1, 
       split_part(numero_bl, '-', 2) as part2 
       from livraisons 
ORDER BY part2 desc,part1 desc limit 1
```

the split_part function split the column 'numero_bl' to 2 parts.so the result is something like that:

part1| part2

001  | 2014

When i try to introduce it inside Python code it returns correct values using **ascending order** but **returns ('None',) when it comes to descending order**

here's a simple version of my function in python:

```
def set_numero_bl(self, cr, uid, ids,name,arg,context=None):
        res={}   
        cr.execute("""select split_part(numero_bl, '-', 1) as part1,
                    split_part(numero_bl, '-', 2) as part2 
                    from livraisons 
                    ORDER BY part2 desc,part1 desc limit 1""")
        execution = cr.fetchone()
        part1 = execution[0]
        part2 = execution[1]
        if part1:
              if part2:
                annee = int(part2)
                nombre = int(part1)+1
                valeur_final= str('%0*d' % (3, nombre))+"-"+str(annee)
                for livraisons in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
                    res[livraisons.id]= valeur_final
        else: 
            valeur_final= str('%0*d' % (3, 1))+"-"+datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y')
            for livraisons in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
                res[livraisons.id]= valeur_final
        return res
```

of course when i won't put the 'else clause' it will return ('None',)

Please is there anyway to fix it or to solve it in any other way?

Thank you

Comment: First, in general you should avoid modelling data like that. That should be two fields.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.yes i know it would be more easier to manipulate it if they were two separate fields but i'm kinda obliged to store it in one field due to some constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out a way to solve my problem.
I changed my query to this

```
cr.execute("""select max(numero_bl) as part from livraisons 
           where split_part(numero_bl, '-', 2) >= %s""",
        ((datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y')),))
```

First ,I keep only records where the **year part is greater than the current year**, after that i take **the max value of my field 'numero_bl'**

here's the full code if anyone is interested:

```
 def set_numero_bl(self, cr, uid, ids,name,arg,context=None):
    res={}   
    cr.execute("""select max(numero_bl) as part 
                 from livraisons 
        where split_part(numero_bl, '-', 2) >= %s""", 
        ((datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y')),)) 
    valeur = cr.fetchone()[0]
    if valeur:
        value = valeur.split('-'); 
        nombre = int(value[0])+1
        valeur_final= str('%0*d' % (3, nombre))+"-"+datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y')
        for livraisons in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
            res[livraisons.id]= valeur_final
    else: 
        valeur_final= str('%0*d' % (3, 1))+"-"+datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y')
        for livraisons in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
            res[livraisons.id]= valeur_final
    return res
```

Thank you all for your replies

Answer (score 0):

There are nulls in that column. When you ask for a descending order nulls will come first:

```
select *
from (values (1), (null)) s(a)
order by a desc;
 a 
---

 1
(2 rows)
```

If you want to keep nulls then tell it to order nulls last

```
select *
from (values (1), (null)) s(a)
order by a desc nulls last;
 a 
---
 1

(2 rows)
```

Or just filter out the nulls

```
select *
from (values (1), (null)) s(a)
where a is not null
order by a desc;
 a 
---
 1
(1 row)
```

Comment: i've thought that too but there are no nulls,all records all filled

Comment: @soukainas What is the result of `select count(*) from livraisons where numero_bl is null;`?